# Does cloning clone also the old MAC address?

Tags: linux, clone, cloning

If I clone my Linux system to other computers will this also clone the old MAC address to the new computers?

---

**EDIT: due to the answer below**

I really know what is a MAC address... And sure Linux is a matter since everything in Linux is a file and thus a network card is just a file inside Linux filesystem and thus cloning byte by byte also may clone this file to other pc's making the new pc have the same MAC address of Old.

---

**Second Edit**

The MAC address is outside the Linux FS but there is a udev rule for MAC address which will be cloned and thus override the read MAC in the new System.

What I mean if you open the file `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` you can see:

```
# PCI device 0x8086:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:19.0 (e1000e)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"

# PCI device 0x8086:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.5/0000:09:00.0 (e1000e)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth1"
```

Those are mine.

This file will be cloned to the new machine and thus it will override the real MAC and make the file system just read those MAC associated here instead of the real MAC.

Comment: A network card is not "just a file inside Linux filesystem" -- it exists outside Linux and will maintain its MAC address, even if you install a different operating system on the computer.

Comment: Yes sure it's outside but friend there is a rule for MAC address in  the udev directory. This will be cloned and this will override the new MAC address. I've recently reach that and  I'm now trying to solve it

Answer (score 4):

Your MAC address is a hardware identifier for network cards and as such has nothing to to with your Linux system. The answer is no.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address

Comment: I really know what is a MAC address... And sure Linux is a matter since everything in Linux is a file and thus a network card is just a file inside Linux filesystem and thus cloning byte by byte also may clone this file to other pc's making the new pc have the same MAC address of Old. So your answer is really illogical specially you are referencing to Wikipedia which is not confidential.

Comment: Everything is a file to a certain point. All that concept means is that it is possible to access any object or device as a file, but that doesn't mean it inherently will carry over. Network cards are hard coded with said MAC address, but if you do override them, then yes, your MAC address will be the same on the other machines, but that simply means removing the overrides you made on the other machines.